# Accelerometer data over BLE are not sent in synch

Tags: node.js, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pi

I am sending temperature, humidity, pressure and accelerometer data over BLE, from [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANO33BLESense) (peripheral) to [Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) (central). I created BLE characteristic per each acceleration dimension `(accX, accY, accZ)`, and I am subscribing to these characteristics.

However, I put counter for each characteristic and realized that data are not sent in order:

```
18 Nov 12:27:35 - [info] [BLE Connect:bf9be48b4648f12e] x = 233
18 Nov 12:27:35 - [info] [BLE Connect:bf9be48b4648f12e] y = 230
18 Nov 12:27:35 - [info] [BLE Connect:bf9be48b4648f12e] z = 236
```

So `x` is read **233 times** while `y` **230 times** vice versa. In ideal scenario, they all should be same.

I am posting my full Arduino code minus comments, hence I believe it might be needed:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <Arduino_HTS221.h>
#include <Arduino_LPS22HB.h>
#include <Arduino_LSM9DS1.h>
  
#define BLE_UUID_ENVIRONMENTAL_SENSING_SERVICE    "181A"
#define BLE_UUID_TEMPERATURE                      "2A6E"
#define BLE_UUID_HUMIDITY                         "2A6F"
#define BLE_UUID_PRESSURE                         "2A6D"
#define BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_SERVICE            "1101"
#define BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_X                  "2101"
#define BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_Y                  "2102"
#define BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_Z                  "2103"

#define BLE_DEVICE_NAME                           "Hako"
#define BLE_LOCAL_NAME                            "Hako"

BLEService environmentalSensingService(BLE_UUID_ENVIRONMENTAL_SENSING_SERVICE);
BLEService accelerometerService(BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_SERVICE);


BLEShortCharacteristic temperatureCharacteristic(BLE_UUID_TEMPERATURE, BLERead | BLENotify);
BLEUnsignedShortCharacteristic humidityCharacteristic(BLE_UUID_HUMIDITY, BLERead | BLENotify);
BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic pressureCharacteristic(BLE_UUID_PRESSURE, BLERead | BLENotify);
BLEShortCharacteristic accelerometerCharacteristic_X(BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_X, BLERead | BLENotify);
BLEShortCharacteristic accelerometerCharacteristic_Y(BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_Y, BLERead | BLENotify);
BLEShortCharacteristic accelerometerCharacteristic_Z(BLE_UUID_ACCELEROMETER_Z, BLERead | BLENotify);

#define ENV_SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL                (1000)
#define ACC_SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL                (1000)

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
  float temperature;
  float humidity;
  float pressure;
  bool updated = false;
} env_sensor_data_t;

env_sensor_data_t envSensorData;

typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
  float accX;
  float accY;
  float accZ;
  bool updated = false;
} acc_sensor_data_t;

acc_sensor_data_t accSensorData;

#define BLE_LED_PIN                               LED_BUILTIN


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println( "BLE Example - Environmental Sensing Service (ESS)" );
  pinMode( BLE_LED_PIN, OUTPUT );
  digitalWrite( BLE_LED_PIN, LOW );
  // Without Serial when using USB power bank HTS sensor seems to needs some time for setup
  delay(10);
  if (!HTS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize humidity temperature sensor!");
    while (1);
  }
  if (!BARO.begin()) {
    Serial.println( "Failed to initialize pressure sensor!" );
    while (1);
  }
  if (!IMU.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize IMU!");
    while (1);
  }
  if (!setupBleMode()) {
    while (1);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println( "BLE initialized. Waiting for clients to connect." );
  }
}

void loop() {
  bleTask();
  if (envSensorTask()) {
    envPrintTask();
  }
  if (accSensorTask()) {
    accPrintTask();
  }
}

bool envSensorTask() {
  static long previousMillis = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); 
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis < ENV_SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
    return false;
  }
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
  envSensorData.temperature = HTS.readTemperature();
  envSensorData.humidity = HTS.readHumidity();
  envSensorData.pressure = BARO.readPressure() * 1000; // kPa -> Pa
  envSensorData.updated = true;
  return envSensorData.updated;
}

bool accSensorTask() {
  static long previousMillis2 = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis2 = millis();
  float x = 0.00, y = 0.00, z = 0.00;
  if (currentMillis2 - previousMillis2 < ACC_SENSOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
    return false;
  }
  previousMillis2 = currentMillis2;
  if(IMU.accelerationAvailable()){
    IMU.readAcceleration(x, y, z);
    accSensorData.accX = x;
    accSensorData.accY = y;
    accSensorData.accZ = z;
    accSensorData.updated = true;
  }
  return accSensorData.updated;
}

bool setupBleMode() {
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    return false;
  }

  BLE.setDeviceName(BLE_DEVICE_NAME);
  BLE.setLocalName(BLE_LOCAL_NAME);
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(environmentalSensingService);
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(accelerometerService);

  environmentalSensingService.addCharacteristic(temperatureCharacteristic);
  environmentalSensingService.addCharacteristic(humidityCharacteristic);
  environmentalSensingService.addCharacteristic(pressureCharacteristic);
  accelerometerService.addCharacteristic(accelerometerCharacteristic_X);
  accelerometerService.addCharacteristic(accelerometerCharacteristic_Y);
  accelerometerService.addCharacteristic(accelerometerCharacteristic_Z);
  
  BLE.addService(environmentalSensingService);
  BLE.addService(accelerometerService);

  temperatureCharacteristic.writeValue(0);
  humidityCharacteristic.writeValue(0);
  pressureCharacteristic.writeValue(0);
  accelerometerCharacteristic_X.writeValue(0);
  accelerometerCharacteristic_Y.writeValue(0);
  accelerometerCharacteristic_Z.writeValue(0);

  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEConnected, blePeripheralConnectHandler);
  BLE.setEventHandler(BLEDisconnected, blePeripheralDisconnectHandler);

  BLE.advertise();

  return true;
}

void bleTask()
{
  const uint32_t BLE_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10;
  static uint32_t previousMillis = 0;
  uint32_t currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= BLE_UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    BLE.poll();
  }

  if (envSensorData.updated) {
    // BLE defines Temperature UUID 2A6E Type sint16 ( see XML links )
    // Unit is in degrees Celsius with a resolution of 0.01 degrees Celsius
    int16_t temperature = round(envSensorData.temperature * 100.0);
    temperatureCharacteristic.writeValue(temperature);

    // BLE defines Humidity UUID 2A6F Type uint16
    // Unit is in percent with a resolution of 0.01 percent
    uint16_t humidity = round(envSensorData.humidity * 100.0);
    humidityCharacteristic.writeValue(humidity);

    // BLE defines Pressure UUID 2A6D Type uint32
    // Unit is in Pascal with a resolution of 0.1 Pa
    uint32_t pressure = round(envSensorData.pressure * 10.0);
    pressureCharacteristic.writeValue(pressure);
    envSensorData.updated = false;
  }

  if (accSensorData.updated) {
    // BLE does not define accelerometer UUID
    // Alls units is in G
    int16_t accelerometer_X = round(accSensorData.accX * 100.0);
    accelerometerCharacteristic_X.writeValue(accelerometer_X);
    
    int16_t accelerometer_Y = round(accSensorData.accY * 100.0);
    accelerometerCharacteristic_Y.writeValue(accelerometer_Y);

    int16_t accelerometer_Z = round(accSensorData.accZ * 100.0);
    accelerometerCharacteristic_Z.writeValue(accelerometer_Z);
 
    envSensorData.updated = false;
  }
}

void envPrintTask() {
  Serial.print( "Temperature = " );
  Serial.print( envSensorData.temperature );
  Serial.println( " °C" );

  Serial.print( "Humidity    = " );
  Serial.print( envSensorData.humidity );
  Serial.println( " %" );

  Serial.print( "Pressure = " );
  Serial.print( envSensorData.pressure );
  Serial.println( " Pa" );

  Serial.print(temperatureCharacteristic.subscribed());
  Serial.print(humidityCharacteristic.subscribed());
  Serial.println(pressureCharacteristic.subscribed());
}

void accPrintTask() {
  Serial.print("AccX = ");
  Serial.print(accSensorData.accX);
  Serial.println(" G");

  Serial.print("AccY = ");
  Serial.print(accSensorData.accY);
  Serial.println(" G");

  Serial.print("AccZ = ");
  Serial.print( accSensorData.accZ );
  Serial.println(" G");

  Serial.print(accelerometerCharacteristic_X.subscribed());
  Serial.print(accelerometerCharacteristic_Y.subscribed());
  Serial.println(accelerometerCharacteristic_Z.subscribed());
}

void blePeripheralConnectHandler(BLEDevice central) {
  digitalWrite(BLE_LED_PIN, HIGH);
  Serial.print(F( "Connected to central: " ));
  Serial.println(central.address());
}

void blePeripheralDisconnectHandler( BLEDevice central ) {
  digitalWrite(BLE_LED_PIN, LOW);
  Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central: "));
  Serial.println(central.address());
}
```

I am reading the data on Pi via in Node.js environment via [@abandonware/noble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble) library.

I will only post the related part, where I subscribe to characteristics first, then I read the data. You can see the **counters** at the end.

```
for (const [key, character] of Object.entries(ALL.characteristics)) {

                    // Check the notify bit, if not set, set it. //
                    if (character.properties.includes("notify")) {
                        const descriptors = await character.discoverDescriptorsAsync().catch(e => send(e));
                        for (const [key, descriptor] of Object.entries(descriptors)) {
                            node.log(descriptor);
                            let descriptorData = await descriptor.readValueAsync().catch(e => send(e));
                            if (descriptorData[0] === bufferChecker[0] || descriptorData[1] === bufferChecker [1]) {
                                node.log(`The ${character.name} ${character.uuid} notify bit is disabled.`);
                                node.log("Enabling notification bit...");
                                descriptor.writeValueAsync(notifySetter).catch(e => send(e));
                                node.log (`Notification for ${character.name} characteristic is enabled.`);
                            } else {
                                node.log(`The ${character.name} ${character.uuid} notify bit is already enabled.`);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        node.log(`Notification is not allowed for ${character.name} characteristic.`)
                    }
                }

                for (const [key, character] of Object.entries(ALL.characteristics)) {
                    character.on('data', (data) => {
                        if (character.uuid === '2a6d') {
                            data = data.readUInt32LE() * decimalSetter[1];
                            environmentalData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterPres++;
                        } else if (character.uuid === '2a6e') {
                            data = data.readUInt16LE() * decimalSetter[0];
                            environmentalData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterTemp++;
                        } else if (character.uuid === '2a6f') {
                            data = data.readUInt16LE() * decimalSetter[0];
                            environmentalData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterHum++;
                        } else if (character.uuid === '2101') {
                            data = data.readInt16LE() * decimalSetter[0];
                            accData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterAccX++;
                        } else if (character.uuid === '2102') {
                            data = data.readInt16LE() * decimalSetter[0];
                            accData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterAccY++;
                        } else if (character.uuid === '2103') {
                            data = data.readInt16LE() * decimalSetter[0];
                            accData.payload[character.name] = data.toFixed(2);
                            counterAccZ++;
                        }
                        node.log("x = " + counterAccX);
                        node.log("y = " + counterAccY);
                        node.log("z = " + counterAccZ);
                        // Sends Temp., Hum., and Pres. data together.
                        if ( (counterHum + counterPres + counterTemp) % 3 == 0 && (counterHum + counterPres + counterTemp) !== 0){
                            send(environmentalData);
                        }
                      });
                    // Character data event listener END //
                }
```

I asked the same question at [Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-send-accelerometer-data-over-ble/926450/3) as well.

Comment: @ukBaz had provided answer that mention we can't know the exact reason due to asynchronous tasks also suggested sending all x, y, z together in one characteristic. He provided a [link](https://punchthrough.com/ble-throughput-part-4/) that explains maximising  BLE throughput. He provided a [link](https://lancaster-university.github.io/microbit-docs/resources/bluetooth/bluetooth_profile.html) for a custom Bluetooth profile that contains accelerometer characteristic. I am sharing these as they might be useful to some. No idea why he deleted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The peripherals GATT server only sends data if the measured value has really changed. This behaviour saves energy and bandwidth. I think your observation is therefore perfectly normal.

Comment: I am already writing a new value per certain interval. They are all changing in order. If the `x` is 0.03, then if I write the same value, it is sent again.

Comment: Depending on the configuration of the characteristic it is not sufficient to simply write a new value, it must also be different from the previous values. Have a look for server-initiated updates 
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html#gatt_roles

Comment: Hi @Risto, if that is the case I should not get same data. However, I am getting it. For example, x = 0.4 then again 0.4 then again etc.